# MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in an INSERT after TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I'm trying to make a trigger that detect when you insert a repeated value in the column *flightTicketID* of the table **refund** and then inserts some data on another table.

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS refunded_tickets//
CREATE TRIGGER refunded_tickets
BEFORE INSERT ON refund
for each row
    BEGIN
        IF new.flightTicketID IN (SELECT flightTicketID FROM refund WHERE accepted = 1) THEN
            INSERT INTO RefundsAlterations(passengerID, flightTicketID, comment)
            SELECT (passengerID, new.flightTicketID, "Refund of a ticket already processed correcty")
            FROM  refund INNER JOIN claims ON claimID.refundID = refund.refundID
            WHERE new.refundID = claimID.refundID;
        END IF;
    END //
    delimiter ;
```

This appears to be ok, but then when I try to insert values into the table to see if the trigger it's working, using the INSERT INTO below, I get his error: *Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s).*

```
 INSERT INTO refund (refundID, flightTicketID, argument, accepted, amount)
 VALUES (10000, 32862, 'Flight Delayed', 1, 264);
```

If I remove the trigger, the Insert works right, so I suppose I'm doing something wrong with the trigger. Does anyone know what it could be? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Remove brackets from `SELECT (passengerID, new.flightTicketID, "Refund of a ticket already processed correcty") FROM  refund`

Just say 

`SELECT passengerID, new.flightTicketID, "Refund of a ticket already processed correcty" FROM  refund`

Answer (score 1):

Thank Ashok Anumula for the answer.

The problem was that the SELECT syntaxis in the trigger's INSERT, the correct one was:

```
SELECT passengerID, new.flightTicketID, "Refund of a ticket already processed correcty" FROM  refund
```

The same but without the brackets.